# Let $C_1(O_1, r)$ and $C_2(O_2, r)$ be two congruent secant circles. Calculate in function of the $r$, the area of the quadrilateral $AO_1BO_2$.

Tags: circles, area, quadrilateral

Let $C_1(O_1, r)$ and $C_2(O_2, r)$ be two congruent secant circles, so that $C_1 \cap C_2$ = {A, B} and $O_1 \in C_2, O_2 \in C_1$. Calculate in function of  the radius, the area of the quadrilateral $AO_1BO_2$....

**MY IDEAS**.

My drawing:
(the wrong drawing)
[image]

THE RIGHT DRAWING

[image]

Okey, so the first thing I have thought of is the theorem that calculates the area of a quadrilateral using $r$.

> A()= p*r
> where p=semiperimeter

Then I realised that $AO_1BO_2$ is a rhombus because $AO_1=O_1B=O_2B=O_2A=$Radius of the circles (because the 2 circles are congruent)

I don't know what else to do forward. All ideas are welcome! Thank you!!!

Comment: From what I understand, you are asking to find the area of this rhombus formed by the four points, which are the two centers and the two points of intersections. But are you asking that in terms of the radius only? Because if that's the case, then there is no one specific case. There are infinitely many intersecting circles. Please correct me if I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: @VizDracViz I am asking that in terms of the radius of the inscribed circle

Comment: you need to elaborate. Yes, we can obtain an expression in terms of the radius, but not just the radius. We will need another variable, like the angle OAB, or the distance between their centers.

Comment: Do you mean the radius of the circle inscribed in the rhombus?

Comment: @VizDracViz I was thinking about that. I found the problem in a math gathering and this is the requirement of the problem. Maybe we cam get another variable and the remove it by simplification

Comment: @IonelaBuciu, think about it, there are infinitely many rhombi with the same side length(in this case, side length is the radius of these circles) which are not congruent and don't have the same area. Therefore, to find the are of this quadrilateral(rhombus), we need another parameter(variable).

Comment: @Hisham That is what I understand from the requirement of the problem. Please correct me if I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: @IonelaBuciu, you can source or share the original problem, so that we can help in understanding it clearly.

Comment: @VizDracViz I'm sorry, but the original source of the problem it isn't in English, so you won't understand it. Thia is the translation of it...

Comment: Then it would be better to include the inscribed circle in the drawing and specify it is the radius of the inscribed circle in the question. Or else people would get confused with the radius of the congruent circles. So, you had better edit the question.

Comment: @Hisham Done! Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: It would be good to include the inscribed circle in the drawing too.

Comment: @Hisham I can't do it right now. In 1 hour I will edit it.

Comment: Please, use Geogebra or Desmos for your figures : it's so easy and the result is so neat !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the radius of the inscribed circle.

Let $C$ be the tangent point of the inscribed circle with $AO_2$.

Let $O'$ be the center of the inscribed circle.

Since $\angle{O'CA}=90^\circ$, we have
$$\text{Area}(O'AO_2)=\frac 12\times O'C\times AO_2=\frac{rR}{2}$$

Similarly, we have
$$\text{Area}(O'AO_1)=\text{Area}(O'O_1B)=\text{Area}(O'BO_2)=\frac{rR}{2}$$

Therefore, the area of the quadrilateral $AO_1BO_2$ is
$$4\times\frac{rR}{2}=\color{red}{2rR}$$

---

**Added 1** :

I realized that I did not use the condition that $O_1 \in C_2, O_2 \in C_1$ from which we can say that $O_1O_2=r$.

So, we can say that $\triangle{AO_1O_2}$ is an equilateral triangle, so we have
$$\text{Area}(AO_1O_2)=\frac 12\times r\times \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}r=\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}r^2$$

Therefore, the area of $AO_1BO_2$ is
$$2\times\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}r^2=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}r^2}$$

---

**Added 2** :

> why $O_1O_2$ equals ths radius?

The condition $O_1 \in C_2$ means that $O_1$ is **on** the circle $C_2$.

The condition $O_2 \in C_1$ means that $O_2$ is **on** the circle $C_1$.

It follows from these that $O_1O_2=r$.

> that means my drawing is made wrong?

Your drawing is not correct.

$O_1$ has to be **on** the circle $C_2$, and $O_2$ has to be **on** the circle $C_1$.

Comment: Hey! Thank youuu sooo much for your response, but I actually wanted to tell that I realise  r stans for the radius of the inscribed circle. Im sorry, its my fault. Can you please solve the problem using r as the radius? Thank youuuuuuu so much, again.

Comment: im saying sorry, again!!!!!

Comment: Okey, so what i said, in my english, means that r is the radius of those circles, sorry for another misunderstanding, I'm hallucinating.

Comment: I'm not familiar with maths words in English, so I have a bad choice of words...

Comment: I found the problem in a math gathering and this is the requirement of the problem. Maybe we cam get another variable and the remove it by simplification...

Comment: sorry for another question, but why $O_1 O_2$ equals ths radius??

Comment: that means my drawing is made wrong?? I didnt put O1 in the line of the circle, but in it. Corect me if i'm wrong

Comment: Okey, thank youuuuu sooo much! I puted the right drawing. I can give you the bounty in 6 hours...Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The function that describes the area of rhombus $AO_1BO_2$ is
$$\begin{align}f()&=\frac 12O_1O_2\times AB\\&=\frac 12O_1O_2\times2\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{O_1O_2}2\right)^2}\\f(x)&=\frac 12x\sqrt{(2r)^2-x^2}\\x&=O_1O_2, 0\lt x\lt 2r\\f\prime(x)&=0\Rightarrow x=r\sqrt2\end{align}$$

Therefore, the area of rhombus $AO_1BO_2$ is described by the function
$$f:(0, 2r)\to (0, r\sqrt 2), f(x)=\frac 12x\sqrt{(2r)^2-x^2}$$ with a maximum of $$f(r\sqrt 2)=r^2\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$$

In terms of the radius on inner circle and the radii of the given congruent circles, the problem is elementary since the rhombus is also a parallelogram and the area becomes $$side\times height=r\times 2r_{\text{inner circle}}$$

Comment: Hey! Thank youuu sooo much for your response, but I actually wanted to tell that I realise r stans for the radius of the inscribed circle. Im sorry, its my fault. Can you please solve the problem using r as the radius? Thank youuuuuuu so much, again.